# Straight line calculation/forecast

Tags: spotfire

I have 4 columns of data: store name, ship date start, ship date end, #of boxes.  I would like in Spotfire create new columns or rows for the time period listed by month and have the monthly #of boxes be calculated and populated.  For example Jan 2019 to Dec 2019 for 1200 boxes would mean 100 boxes per month.

Comment: you need to provide an example dataset and an example output of what you are looking for.

Comment: While this seems straightforward, there are a few reasons why an example dataset would help -- is the "ship date start" column legitimately "Jan 2019" or is it in date format, '1/1/2019'?  Each of these will require different code.  Similarly, if you have a Ship Date Start of '1/1/2019' and a ship date end of '12/10/2019', is that 12 months, or 11.32 months?  Help us help you.